# AES and message properties

Tags: aes, integrity, confidentiality

An active attacker changes the ciphertext which was made using the AES cipher algorithm.
Which message properties are preserved even though that change was made. Choose one of the below:

1) Integrity of the message.

2) Confidentiality of the message.

3) Confidentiality and integrity of the message.

4) Nothing of the above.

I know that AES uses block encryption, so if we change a random byte in the original message the whole block will decrypt incorrectly (we lose integrity) , so I would go with confidentiality.

Am I right?

Comment: Exam questions? Please post the name and e-mail address of your supervisor so we could mail the answers directly to him.

Comment: Yes, it's a last year's exam question. I don't see a problem with asking it. I also wrote what the answer should be and why, so basically I just need confirmation of the correctness/incorrectness of my answer and my thought process, and not a direct answer.

Comment: Integrity of the message.

Comment: AES itself only permutes a fixed size block. To encrypt actual messages you need to choose a mode of operation. The security properties depend on that mode.

Comment: Exactly. But the question doesn't specify which mode (ECB,CBC,..) is used, so there must be a general answer to this question.

Comment: @RunoTheDog There is no general answer, it's a bad question. With unauthenticated encryption (CBC, etc.) you in theory get confidentiality but not integrity. But it's quite likely in practice that a padding oracle (or similar) destroys confidentiality as well. With authenticated encryption (GCM, etc.) confidentiality and integrity of the message are preserved. I guess the asker implicitly meant unauthenticated encryption but without oracles being applicable, making 2) the expected answer.